# ASP.NET Core URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-core

I am trying to redirect my website from www to non-www rules as well as http to https (https://example.com) in the middleware. I used to make those redirection change in the web.config such as:

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirects to www.domain.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" 
            stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

I am new to asp.net core and would like to know how can i make those redirection in my middleware? I read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting but it didn't help me to force redirect my www to non-www.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the following NuGet package:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite
```

Add the following line:

```
app.UseCustomRewriter();
```

within:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

Before calling `.UseMvc` method.

And add the following extensions class to your project:

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomRewriter(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()
            .AddPermanentRedirect("(.*)/$", "$1");

        return app.UseRewriter(options);
    }
}
```

Within RewriteOptions you can provide your rewrite configuration.

Hoops this will help you out.

Best regards,
Colin

Comment: I feel like this answer should be updated with latest dotnet core 2.2 documentation as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55838856/593985).