# ASP.NET Core url rewrite only domain

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to change my old domain to new one and I have huge data on my website. I need to change only my domain by url rewriting.

When I request:

```
www.myolddomain.net/article/seo-friendly-url-for-this-article
```

I need to have a permanent (301) redirect to:

```
www.mynewdomain.com/article/seo-friendly-url-for-this-article
```

How ca I do this in asp.net core?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Without knowing your situation I would suggest responding with statuscode 301 and the `Location` header [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301)

Comment: Use statuscode 307 for a temporary redirect and 301 for a permanent (the browser will remember)

Comment: @hatef - have you tried the approach below? Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

It's pretty simple.

1. Drop a IISUrlRewrite.xml file in the root of your application folder. Mark it as "Content" and "Copy to output directory" set to true, looks like this in your csproj

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="IISUrlRewrite.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

2. Add following content in the file

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>    
    <rule name="Host replace - Old to new" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.myolddomain\.net" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mynewdomain.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

3. Register the URL rewrite module in the `Configure` method of your `Startup.cs` file

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{   
    // Irrelevant code omitted

    using (var iisUrlRewriteStreamReader = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "IISUrlRewrite.xml")))
    {
        var options = new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(iisUrlRewriteStreamReader);
        app.UseRewriter(options);
    }

    // Irrelevant code omitted
}
```