# ASP.NET Core Url Rewrite Only Domain Name for a Subsite www.olddomain.com/subsite

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I'm trying to configure the URL Redirect from https://www.olddomain.com/Subsite to https://www.newdomain.com/Subsite

I used solution from [ASP.NET Core url rewrite only domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55837817/asp-net-core-url-rewrite-only-domain)

```
<rule name="Host replace - Old to new" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.olddomain\.com" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://wwww.newdomain.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```

When opening the subsite https://www.olddomain.com/Subsite, I expect the request to be redirected https://www.newdomain.com/Subsite but the actual redirect goes to https://www.olddomain.com/Subsitehttps://www.newdomain.com

Comment: 1. I tried your code with `app.UseRewriter(rewriteOpts);`. But it works fine for me. Could you please show us a way to reproduce?  2. According to your last  `https://www.olddomain.com/Subsitehttps://www.newdomain.com`, I doubt it is redirected by the `Redirect: /Subsitehttps://www.newdomain.com` header.  How do you apply this rule? Do you use this in IIS or use a Rewrite Middleware?

Comment: Thanks @itminus, I used Rewrite Middleware ... 

The following codes at Startup.cs


                    `var options = new RewriteOptions()
                                     .AddIISUrlRewrite(iisUrlRewriteStreamReader);
                    app.UseRewriter(options);`

There's a F5 load balancer in between - could that be possible culprit?